# Alternating Series - Error Bound: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2(-1)^n}{n^{0.9}}$

Tags: calculus, approximation

Evaluating the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2(-1)^n}{n^{0.9}}
$$
with an $|\text{error}|<0.001$.

I know that you would have to take the abs value which would then leave the problem at 2/(n^0.9).. That's all I know..

Comment: You could take a look at the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Formulation) saying that if $|a_n|$ decreases monotonically and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ then the alternating series converges. Moreover, with
$$
S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n-1} |a_n|, \quad S_\infty = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} |a_n|
$$ one has
$$
\left|S_\infty-S_N\right|\le \left| a_{N+1}\right|
$$ then one may apply it to $a_n=\dfrac2{n^{0.9}}$, giving
$$
\dfrac2{n^{0.9}}<0.001 \implies n> 2000^{1/0.9}\approx \color{red}{4654}.
$$

Comment: @Oliver Oloa Question, how did you get n > 2000^(1/0.9) ?

Comment: From $\dfrac2{n^{0.9}}<0.001$ we have $\dfrac2{0.001}<n^{0.9}$ that is $2000<n^{0.9}$ and $2000^{1/0.9}<n$.

Comment: The answer was 4653, but thank you.